# Accessing x and y coordinates of a POLYGON in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In my database. I have a spatial column called coordinates which is of datatype POLYGON. so for example. The lunch room has coordinates POLYGON(0 2, 1 2, 3 2, 5 2, 0 2). That's just a hypothetical example.

How do I access the individual x and y coordinates for each polygon in the database?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
select 
t.coordinates.STAsText() 
from your_tablename as t
```